How to interact with 3D Slicer from an external Python environment?
I have attempted to use the pyigtl and slicerio libraries, but neither was successful in displaying the three surfaces of the instrument tip in real-time within 3D Slicer. My requirement is to execute this externally, allowing modifications or displays to 3D Slicer. I can successfully achieve my needs within the Python console of 3D Slicer, but now I need to execute it externally.
I want to interact with the 3D Slicer environment from my Python project but I'm facing issues accessing the interfaces provided by 3D Slicer in an external environment. I would like to post a question on Stack Overflow regarding this issue. Below is the code that outlines my requirements:

import slicer
import vtk

# Replace with the name of the loaded volume node

volume_node = slicer.util.getNode('verse808_seg')

# Get the volume data extent

image_data = volume_node.GetImageData()
extent = image_data.GetExtent()
print("Volume extent:", extent)

# Replace with the coordinates of the point to use as a reference

point = \[1, 1, 1\]  # Your point coordinates

# Get the RASToIJKMatrix of the volume node

ras_to_ijk_matrix = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
volume_node.GetRASToIJKMatrix(ras_to_ijk_matrix)

# Convert the RAS coordinates of the point to IJK coordinates

ras_point = \[point\[0\], point\[1\], point\[2\], 1.0\]  # Add homogeneous coordinate
ijk_point = ras_to_ijk_matrix.MultiplyPoint(ras_point)\[:3\]  # Take the first three coordinates, ignoring the homogeneous coordinate

# Print the converted IJK coordinates for debugging

print("IJK Coordinates:", ijk_point)

# Check if the IJK coordinates are within the extent

if (extent\[0\] \<= ijk_point\[0\] \<= extent\[1\] and
extent\[2\] \<= ijk_point\[1\] \<= extent\[3\] and
extent\[4\] \<= ijk_point\[2\] \<= extent\[5\]):
print("IJK point is within the volume extent.")

    # Create a fiducial node and add control points (using fiducials instead)
    fiducial_node = slicer.mrmlScene.AddNewNodeByClass('vtkMRMLMarkupsFiducialNode', 'F')
    fiducial_node.AddControlPoint(ras_point[0], ras_point[1], ras_point[2])
    
    # Update display
    slicer.app.processEvents()
    
    # Get slice nodes
    slice_node_red = slicer.util.getNode('vtkMRMLSliceNodeRed')
    slice_node_yellow = slicer.util.getNode('vtkMRMLSliceNodeYellow')
    slice_node_green = slicer.util.getNode('vtkMRMLSliceNodeGreen')
    
    # Get slice logic
    red_logic = slicer.app.layoutManager().sliceWidget('Red').sliceLogic()
    yellow_logic = slicer.app.layoutManager().sliceWidget('Yellow').sliceLogic()
    green_logic = slicer.app.layoutManager().sliceWidget('Green').sliceLogic()
    
    # Set slice positions and force update the display
    slice_node_red.SetSliceOffset(ras_point[2])      # Z slice
    slice_node_yellow.SetSliceOffset(ras_point[0])   # X slice
    slice_node_green.SetSliceOffset(ras_point[1])    # Y slice
    slicer.app.processEvents()
    
    # Print debugging information
    print("Red slice offset:", slice_node_red.GetSliceOffset())
    print("Yellow slice offset:", slice_node_yellow.GetSliceOffset())
    print("Green slice offset:", slice_node_green.GetSliceOffset())
    
    # Lock slice views to prevent auto-reset
    red_composite_node = red_logic.GetSliceCompositeNode()
    yellow_composite_node = yellow_logic.GetSliceCompositeNode()
    green_composite_node = green_logic.GetSliceCompositeNode()
    
    red_composite_node.SetLinkedControl(False)
    yellow_composite_node.SetLinkedControl(False)
    green_composite_node.SetLinkedControl(False)
    
    # Force refresh the view
    slicer.app.processEvents()
    
    # Add event listeners to ensure slice positions do not reset
    def onSliceNodeModified(caller, event):
        slice_node_red.SetSliceOffset(ras_point[2])      # Z slice
        slice_node_yellow.SetSliceOffset(ras_point[0])   # X slice
        slice_node_green.SetSliceOffset(ras_point[1])    # Y slice
        slicer.app.processEvents()
    
    slice_node_red.AddObserver(vtk.vtkCommand.ModifiedEvent, onSliceNodeModified)
    slice_node_yellow.AddObserver(vtk.vtkCommand.ModifiedEvent, onSliceNodeModified)
    slice_node_green.AddObserver(vtk.vtkCommand.ModifiedEvent, onSliceNodeModified)
    
    # Force refresh the view again
    slicer.app.processEvents()

else:
print("Error: Point is outside the volume extent.")

I can successfully achieve my needs within the Python console of 3D Slicer, but now I need to execute it externally.
import slicer
import vtk

# Replace with the name of the loaded volume node

volume_node = slicer.util.getNode('verse808_seg')

# Get the volume data extent

image_data = volume_node.GetImageData()
extent = image_data.GetExtent()
print("Volume extent:", extent)

# Replace with the coordinates of the point to use as a reference

point = \[1, 1, 1\]  # Your point coordinates

# Get the RASToIJKMatrix of the volume node

ras_to_ijk_matrix = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
volume_node.GetRASToIJKMatrix(ras_to_ijk_matrix)

# Convert the RAS coordinates of the point to IJK coordinates

ras_point = \[point\[0\], point\[1\], point\[2\], 1.0\]  # Add homogeneous coordinate
ijk_point = ras_to_ijk_matrix.MultiplyPoint(ras_point)\[:3\]  # Take the first three coordinates, ignoring the homogeneous coordinate

# Print the converted IJK coordinates for debugging

print("IJK Coordinates:", ijk_point)

# Check if the IJK coordinates are within the extent

if (extent\[0\] \<= ijk_point\[0\] \<= extent\[1\] and
extent\[2\] \<= ijk_point\[1\] \<= extent\[3\] and
extent\[4\] \<= ijk_point\[2\] \<= extent\[5\]):
print("IJK point is within the volume extent.")

    # Create a fiducial node and add control points (using fiducials instead)
    fiducial_node = slicer.mrmlScene.AddNewNodeByClass('vtkMRMLMarkupsFiducialNode', 'F')
    fiducial_node.AddControlPoint(ras_point[0], ras_point[1], ras_point[2])
    
    # Update display
    slicer.app.processEvents()
    
    # Get slice nodes
    slice_node_red = slicer.util.getNode('vtkMRMLSliceNodeRed')
    slice_node_yellow = slicer.util.getNode('vtkMRMLSliceNodeYellow')
    slice_node_green = slicer.util.getNode('vtkMRMLSliceNodeGreen')
    
    # Get slice logic
    red_logic = slicer.app.layoutManager().sliceWidget('Red').sliceLogic()
    yellow_logic = slicer.app.layoutManager().sliceWidget('Yellow').sliceLogic()
    green_logic = slicer.app.layoutManager().sliceWidget('Green').sliceLogic()
    
    # Set slice positions and force update the display
    slice_node_red.SetSliceOffset(ras_point[2])      # Z slice
    slice_node_yellow.SetSliceOffset(ras_point[0])   # X slice
    slice_node_green.SetSliceOffset(ras_point[1])    # Y slice
    slicer.app.processEvents()
    
    # Print debugging information
    print("Red slice offset:", slice_node_red.GetSliceOffset())
    print("Yellow slice offset:", slice_node_yellow.GetSliceOffset())
    print("Green slice offset:", slice_node_green.GetSliceOffset())
    
    # Lock slice views to prevent auto-reset
    red_composite_node = red_logic.GetSliceCompositeNode()
    yellow_composite_node = yellow_logic.GetSliceCompositeNode()
    green_composite_node = green_logic.GetSliceCompositeNode()
    
    red_composite_node.SetLinkedControl(False)
    yellow_composite_node.SetLinkedControl(False)
    green_composite_node.SetLinkedControl(False)
    
    # Force refresh the view
    slicer.app.processEvents()
    
    # Add event listeners to ensure slice positions do not reset
    def onSliceNodeModified(caller, event):
        slice_node_red.SetSliceOffset(ras_point[2])      # Z slice
        slice_node_yellow.SetSliceOffset(ras_point[0])   # X slice
        slice_node_green.SetSliceOffset(ras_point[1])    # Y slice
        slicer.app.processEvents()
    
    slice_node_red.AddObserver(vtk.vtkCommand.ModifiedEvent, onSliceNodeModified)
    slice_node_yellow.AddObserver(vtk.vtkCommand.ModifiedEvent, onSliceNodeModified)
    slice_node_green.AddObserver(vtk.vtkCommand.ModifiedEvent, onSliceNodeModified)
    
    # Force refresh the view again
    slicer.app.processEvents()

else:
print("Error: Point is outside the volume extent.")

